# Laravel - Custom authentification query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-authentication

How can I add `DESC` to the default login sql query?

I mean on default is something like

`select * from users where name = user_name limit 1`.

How can I add

`select * from users where name = user_name ORDER BY id DESC limit 1`?

I know that the name column should contain unique values only, my login system it's different (some predefined users in another table) and I need multiple user registrations with the same name. I just want to login on the last record in the database. Please help me how can I customize the model provider in laravel? I don't know what files to modify for this to work.

This is my LoginController.php but you can ignore it (I added it because some users required it) just look at the default loginController from `php artisan make:auth`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
/**
     * Check either username or email.
     * @return string
     */

public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

      public function username()
    {
        $identity  = Session::get('table_id');
        $fieldName = 'name';
        request()->merge([$fieldName => $identity]);

        return $fieldName;
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login.
     * @param Request $request
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            [
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ],
            [
                'password.required' => 'Password is required',
            ]
        );
    }
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('login_error', trans('auth.failed'));
        throw ValidationException::withMessages(
            [
                'error' => [trans('auth.failed')],
            ]
        );
    }

     protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $remember = true;
        return $this->guard()->attempt(         
            $this->credentials($request), $remember
        );
    }
}
```

All methods in my LoginController overrides methods from `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

Comment: Show your query

Comment: What do you mean? I posted the query I need to add `order by id DESC` in laravel default login query

Comment: It is final sql query. How you get it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace LoginController with the following. I have removed username() method and replaced attemptLogin() method to fetch the last user in your database given your session value of 'table_id'.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->user = $user;
    }
/**
     * Check either username or email.
     * @return string
     */

public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login.
     * @param Request $request
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            [
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ],
            [
                'password.required' => 'Password is required',
            ]
        );
    }
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('login_error', trans('auth.failed'));
        throw ValidationException::withMessages(
            [
                'error' => [trans('auth.failed')],
            ]
        );
    }

protected function attemptLogin(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if (session()->has('table_id') != true) return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => 'No username is set.']);
    $userName = $user->where('name', session('table_id'))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->name;
    $remember = true;
    if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $userName, 'password' => request('password')], $remember)) {
        return redirect()->intended();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example for using the method? This is my LoginController constructor :  `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }` and the login method is the default one `public function login(Request $request)
    {`

Comment: Are you using the default laravel auth login page? What are you trying to do exactly? Have a user enter an email and password, and have it login the last user in the database that matches that email and password?

Comment: Yes I am using the default laravel auth login page but I modified the controller so I can provide the username from a session set earlier in the application. I'm providing the username from a session, the user is only typing a password, if the password matches the username, the user logs in. I just need the login to be made on the latest record for a particular user. I just need to add that ORDER BY clause in the login nothing more the rest works.

Comment: Can you add your controller method for handling the login currently?

Comment: I added it in my main question. All methods in my LoginController overrides methods from `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. I have removed username() method and replaced attemptLogin() method to fetch the last user in your database given your session value of 'table_id'. Let me know if this works. I have also added /App/User model to your alias/importing so you can access the User model. If this works, please accept my answer, if not I will help troubleshoot.

Comment: `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::attemptLogin(), 1 passed in app\Http\Controllers\ ▶`

Comment: I edited the code again, instead injecting the User model into the constructor and removing it from the attemptLogin() method. It should work now. Give it a shot and report back.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from users where name = 1 and 0 = test123 limit 1)` (test123 it's the password from input)

Comment: Added in Auth facade to imports and forgot to add in password column before. Try the code now.

Comment: Thank you , It works but if I don't set session I get this error: `"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"` is there anything I can do if no session is set to either use a random id that would not work on login or give back an error?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code again with a guard to check if the session variable is set. If it's not, it will return back with an error message. Use a foreach loop in your blade template as ($errors->all() as $error) to output the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change/delete any framework files and codes.
in top of your login controller just add this trait:

`use AuthenticatesUsers;`

then you can override all login functions.

for authenticating username/password just override **attemptLogin()** function.

Comment: I did that but I don't know where to add the `->orderBy('id', 'desc')` in the **attemptLogin()** method. Can you please help? This is my method : `protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $remember = true;
        return $this->guard()->attempt(         
            $this->credentials($request), $remember
        );
    }`

Comment: you don't need the 'desc' because you will have a single record if your query find a match, like other answers mentioned to that you should use  `->first()`.

Comment: I really need to be the latest , with the default login is matching the password for the first record.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question right, you want to change default sql query for selecting user when authenticating.
in `attemptLogin` method you call `attempt` and it is in StatefulGuard Interface and the implementation is in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php` so you need to either override full `attempt` method, either the methods in it.

Comment: The `attemptLogin ` it's the default method from `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php` I only added the true value to the remember token so the user gets logged in with "rember me" checked on automatically. Let's put this differently imagine I have nothing in LoginController (I have it but it's the default one without any modifications). How can I add ORDER BY desc in the login query? Even if it's useless in the default LoginController because every name is unique how would I add it?

Comment: Imagine a fresh `php artisan make:auth` login system. I want to add ORDER by DESC in the login query. If you have the possibility make a fresh laravel app (`laravel new blog`) and then `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that works but I believe it will mess something up (I'm not sure) that is why I voted Polaris's answer as the right one.

You can leave the default LoginController and modify the App/User.php like this:
It basically overrides the `retrieveByCredentials` method used in `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;` . The issue is that I believe this method is not normally accessed directly from the `Users.php` so you are not directly overriding it. But for some reason it works :)).

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

        public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (empty($credentials) ||
           (count($credentials) === 1 &&
            array_key_exists('password', $credentials))) {
            return;
        }

        // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
        // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
        // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
        $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

        foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if (Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
                continue;
            }

            if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof Arrayable) {
                $query->whereIn($key, $value);
            } else {
                $query->where($key, $value);
            }
        }

       return $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    }
}
```